# Google Calendar/FullCalendar not loading in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have a WebView in Android that loads a web app that has an embedded Google Calendar/FullCalendar.  That calendar loads in mobile browsers but won't load in the WebView.

I have tried `webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` but that doesn't get it to load either.

```
public class WebView extends AppCompatActivity {

    android.webkit.WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        myWebView = (android.webkit.WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("mywebsite.com");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState ) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        myWebView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        myWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**Does anyone know what I may need to enable/do to get an embedded Google Calendar/FullCalendar to load in a WebView?**

Answer (score 0):

Set the user agent in the `onCreate`:

```
myWebView.getSettings();.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
```